# Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved one - but it lies

Tags: bug, review, edits

I encountered a question in a close-review queue (this may be significant?) and edited it to bring it back on topic. While I was editing it, the notification bar indicate it had been concurrently edited.

[image]

When I completed my edit, I tried to save the edit, but the system rejected it. I was surprised that someone had done a more thorough edit, but I copied/pasted my changes in to a new edit window, and saved it that way.

I checked the revision history..... and found that the "competing" edit was trivial: [See revision history here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/96330/revisions) - note the competing edit removed "using Linq" from the title.....

[image]

Why was my edit not approved? Why is it not "more thorough"?

Comment: A hearty +1 - This (ironic) message has stung me more than I can count.

Comment: Yeah, considering rolfl is also a mod there, the restrictions should be lifted, just a warning... But that's another problem.

Comment: Quite by chance, I had the same "issue" today. Haven't had it so much before. Have the weightings been changed? They've been changed _wrongly_ if so...